# No bashrc in ubuntu Gnome

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I would like to configure my environment variables in Ubuntu version and can't find my bashrc.
Where can I find it?

Comment: see: * ~/.bash_profile
* /etc/environment
* /etc/bash.bashrc
* /etc/profile
* /etc/profile.d

Comment: It should be in your $HOME. The name starts with a dot (`.`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your home dir, e.g. if you are larix, then it is located in:

```
      /home/larix/.bashrc
```

You can see it from your filemanager if it shows "hidden" files (if file name starts with "." it is considered as "hidden" file in linux)

Comment: i founded but dont have any enviroment varible declared..weird

Comment: @user1866731 probably you have newly installed system. Anyway, if there is none, you can declare it on your own. If you are looking for some specific variable - declare it, or you should find it in system-wide settings (e.g. /etc/ see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/127056/where-is-bashrc )